# Access private members of class from callback of a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my code

```
class MyClass {
  private ref: any;
  private ourprogress: any = 0;
  onUploadAll() {
    ref.api(somedata).then(function (snapshot) {
         this.ourprogress++;//Not working
    });
  }
}
```

ourprogress remains unchanged no matter what

Comment: Can arrow function solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
class MyClass {
  private ref: any;
  private ourprogress: any = 0;
  onUploadAll() {
    ref.api(somedata).then((function (snapshot) {
         this.ourprogress++;//Now works
      }).bind(this));
  }
}
```